# Rethrow php exception into higher level catch block

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I am trying to pass an exception from a specific catch block to a more general catch block. However it does not appear to be working. I get a 500 server error when I try the following. Is this even possible?

I realize that there are easy workarounds, but isn't it normal to say, "Hey I don't feel like dealing with this error, let's have the more general exception handler take care of it!"

```
try {
   //some soap stuff
}

catch (SoapFault $sf) {
    throw new Exception('Soap Fault');
}

catch (Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: No, it's not normal to use exceptions to handle flow control.

Comment: Perhaps people need to review the rules for downvoting. If what someone is doing is a bad idea then explain why. If it is a badly formed question then downvote - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33286/downvotes-versus-close-votes-on-questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically this is what you're looking for:

```
try {
    try {
       //some soap stuff
    }    
    catch (SoapFault $sf) {
        throw new Exception('Soap Fault');
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

however I agree that exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control. A better way would be like this:

```
function show_error($message) {
    echo "Error: $message\n";
}

try {
   //some soap stuff
}    
catch (SoapFault $sf) {
    show_error('Soap Fault');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    show_error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: There are some situations, where you need to rethrow an exception. For example, if you have a class constructor and catch inside it an exception (for example for logging the error to a special file), then you would have to rethrow the exception to inform also the construction caller about the error.