# Rethrowing partially caught exceptions?

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I have code that expects to occasionally get a unique index violation when inserting into a remote database. It's not possible to avoid the violation as I need a randomly-generated but human-readable value. Unfortunately PDO just throws a generic PDOException when this happens, so I have a loop that contains this abomination:

```
do {
        ...
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
       if ($e->getCode() === '23000') {
          continue; // have another go
      } else {
          throw new Exception("...", 1, $e); // reraise
      }
} while(there was an exception);
```

I think error trapping is going to be better than search-then-insert because with a four digit code and only a few hundred active codes at any time there will be few collisions.

SO questions like [best practices for catching and re-throwing exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551668/what-are-the-best-practices-for-catching-and-re-throwing-exceptions) and [Rethrow php exception into higher level catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377136/rethrow-php-exception-into-higher-level-catch-block) suggest that even in PHP this is poor practice. I'm both catching an exception I'm 99% sure I'm going to rethrow, and I'm using exceptions for flow control.

Is there a better way to do this in PHP, or is my only alternative to use a stored procedure in the database that returns an error code on failure rather than an exception.

Comment: What about using a switch?

Comment: @Darren where would I use a switch? If I have a single condition plus default switch in the exception handler that's just a verbose form of the if I already have. But I can't see how to replace the loop with a switch. Sorry, I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My conclusion is that there really is no better way to do this in PHP, so I've moved the logic into MySQL where it is slightly less ugly. I'm using error handling rather than searching because that will be faster for the normal case where there's no collision.

Doing a search first would be slower to much slower in PHP (two or more queries) and slightly slower for the normal case in SQL (one extra query), but if there are a lot of collisions it will be faster to do the searches first rather than failing on the insert.

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062 -- duplicate key
    SET @dupe = 1;

SET @dupe = 0;
SET @attemptsLeft = 5;
REPEAT
    SET @user_code = randomString(4);
    INSERT INTO mytable(expires, user_code, users_id)VALUES(p_expires, @user_code, p_users_id);
    SET @attemptsLeft = @attemptsLeft - 1;
    -- if there's a dupe we get the continue handler above
UNTIL @dupe = 0 OR @attemptsLeft <= 0 END REPEAT;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to re-throw the same exception why don't you use just:

```
throw $e;
```

Comment: I could. But that's not the question. I'm asking whether there's a better way to trap only the one error code I care about